# Stop thread is not working with function setRunning(false)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas

I have a project to draw a line using canvas. My project (download [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rga383w6sameq6g/WavePlot312.rar?dl=0))will create a random number and connect them on the line using canvas. It works well. But the problem is that, when my application is running and I click the HOME button then my application will  be crashed such as

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10001
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.waveplot.WaveformView.PlotPoints(WaveformView.java:78)
at com.example.waveplot.WaveformPlotThread.run(WaveformPlotThread.java:35)
```

How to fix it? Thank you so much. 
Let explain my application. My application include three classes:

```
WaveformView.java: class to draw the line in thread with random number.
MainActivity.java: main calss and create the random number and call WaveformView class
WaveformPlotThread: create a thread and manager canvas
```

This is my code
MainActivity.java

```
        private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            numRandom=genNum(0,200)-100;// from -100 to 100
            if(dataIndex1<MAX_SAMPLES) 
                dataY[dataIndex1++] = numRandom;
            else
            {
                dataY[MAX_SAMPLES-1] = numRandom;
               for (int i = 0; i <  WIDTH/10 - 1; i++)
                   //Shift data
                   dataY[i]=dataY[i+1];

            }
            mWaveform.set_data(dataY);
        }
     };
```

WaveformView.java

```
public class WaveformView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    // plot area size
    private final static int WIDTH = 660;
    private static int[] dataX = new int[WIDTH];
    private static int[] dataY = new int[WIDTH];
    private WaveformPlotThread plot_thread; 
    private Paint dataY_color = new Paint();
    private int  index = 0;

    public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        plot_thread = new WaveformPlotThread(getHolder(), this);        
        dataY_color.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        dataY_color.setStrokeWidth(3);

    }   
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){

    }   
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        plot_thread.setRunning(true);
        plot_thread.start();
        //plot_thread.startThread();
    }   
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        Log.d("D","STOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP");

        boolean retry = true;
        plot_thread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry){
            try{
                plot_thread.join();
                retry = false;
            }catch(InterruptedException e){

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        PlotPoints(canvas);

    }

    public void set_data(int[] data1){      
        plot_thread.setRunning(false);
        if(index<WIDTH/10-1)
            index++;
        for(int x=0; x<WIDTH/10-1; x++){
            if(x<(data1.length)){
            dataX[x+1]=(x+1)*WIDTH/66;
            dataY[x] = data1[x];
            }
            else{
                dataY[x] = 0;
            }
        }
        plot_thread.setRunning(true);
    }

    public void PlotPoints(Canvas canvas){
        if(canvas == null) { return ; }
        // clear screen
        canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(20, 20, 20));
        // plot data
        for(int x=0; x<index-1; x++){           
            canvas.drawLine(dataX[x], dataY[x], dataX[x+1], dataY[x+1], dataY_color);
        }

    }

}
```

WaveformPlotThread

```
public class WaveformPlotThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private WaveformView plot_area;
   // private volatile Thread runner;
    private volatile boolean _run=true;

    public WaveformPlotThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, WaveformView view){
        holder = surfaceHolder;
        plot_area = view;
    }
    public void setRunning(boolean run){
        _run = run;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Canvas c;
        while(_run){
        //while(Thread.currentThread() == runner){
            c = null;
            try{
                c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (holder) {
                    plot_area.PlotPoints(c);
                }
            }finally{
                if(c!=null){
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is log file

```
 D/D(9747): STOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOP
 W/SurfaceView(9747): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
 W/System.err(9747): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
 W/System.err(9747):    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1045)
 W/System.err(9747):    at com.example.waveplot.WaveformView.surfaceCreated(WaveformView.java:41)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:609)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:235)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7625)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1047)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1346)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1121)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 W/System.err(9747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
 W/System.err(9747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 W/System.err(9747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 W/System.err(9747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
 W/System.err(9747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
 W/System.err(9747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Solution: Based on suggestion of Veritas I put the function to create new thread in to SurfaceCreated

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    plot_thread = new WaveformPlotThread(getHolder(), this);
    plot_thread.setRunning(true);
    plot_thread.start();

}   
public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    //plot_thread = new WaveformPlotThread(getHolder(), this);      
    dataY_color.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    dataY_color.setStrokeWidth(3);

}
```

Comment: Related: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four things

1. Check for if canvas is null in your PlotPoints method,

   **if(canvas == null) {
          return ; // return silently 
       }**

   Possibly on surface destroyed surfaceholder is returning you a null canvas
2. As isalgueiro suggested make _run as volatile/
3. Make the default value of _run as true, because if somewhere you start this thread without setting _run as true, its quite possible that the thread ends before you can do anything constructive with it. Default value of false has no meaning in your case.
4. Don't extend thread instead implement runnable.

Last two points are more of best practices ..

--EDIT --
For time being create a new Thread in surfaceCreated and then start it, its because your logic for exiting the while loop when _run is set to  false will make the thread complete its run method and the thread will die. The error is self indicative you cannot start a thread once it is already started. Either you reuse your thread by correcting your logic of _run = false/true or adopt a better solution by using  Executor ThreadPool see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html.
For time being you can create a new thread in surfacecreated method instead of constructor

Comment: Thank your first point. However, it still error when I click Home button during running application. Let check my project again

Comment: can you provide the Exception StackTrace

Comment: can you point which line number is 78 in you WaveformView.java

Comment: Could you help me show one example to use it in my code? I am reading it. Thank in advance

Comment: I read your link but I have no idea to resolve my problem. Could you have any way to resolve my problem?

Comment: did you tried this - "For time being create a new Thread in surfaceCreated and start instead of Constructor;

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I could not figure out why the `Thread` would not stop when `setRunning(false)` was called, but I managed to bypass the `NullPointerException` by wrapping `plot_area.PlotPoints()` in another `if(canvas != null)` statement. So your `run()` method in `WaveformPlotThread` would look like this:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    Canvas c;
    while(_run){
    //while(Thread.currentThread() == runner){
        c = null;
        try{
            c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (holder) {
                if(c!=null) {
                    plot_area.PlotPoints(c);
                }
            }
        }finally{
            if(c!=null){
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as a side note, `@Override public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)` is not necessary, and overriding `onDraw()` or `draw()` is not recommended. The whole method can be deleted.

Comment: Thank for your comment. I updated my code as your mention. However, I have problem is that when app. run after 20 seconds, the canvas will not draw. I have no idea to find what is happen in my code. Please check it in here for more detail https://www.dropbox.com/s/s785hn3mmpk8444/WavePlotv2.rar?dl=0  .Note that it only happened in real device. In simulation, it has no problem

Comment: @user8264 I ran your code on a Nexus 7 api 5.1.1, an emulated Nexus 5 api 5.1.0 and an emulated LG Optimus api 4.1.1. They all ran fine. Except for the Optimus, which did not scale the `SurfaceView` properly, but it still drew the plot correctly. Unfortunately I do not have any other devices (other than more emulators) to test on. It may be specific to your device.

Comment: Please download my code and run it after 1 minutes. You can see the problem. I recorded the error and post https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuutH2Pf3Yk . Currently, I solved it by delete plot_thread.setRunning(false); and plot_thread.setRunning(true); in the set_data function

Comment: @user8264 I ran it again for about ten minutes with no issue. Are there any errors in logcat when it occurs?

Comment: Actually, I can not found any error in logcat. It just did not go to  plot_area.PlotPoints(c); in WaveformPlotThread. I printed the _run flag but it still is true value. However, I just deleted two line plot_thread.setRunning(false); and plot_thread.setRunning(true); then it works well. I have no idea for detecting the error. I am running it in Samsung Galaxy S2 and Note 2

Answer (score 0):

Make `_run` volatile, so reads and writes are atomic. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

```
public class WaveformPlotThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private WaveformView plot_area;
    private volatile boolean _run = false;
```

Comment: How to use it in my applicaton?

Comment: It did not work. Please download my project and try run it with your edit. Note that it will crash when the application is running and you press home button